# What's the word for the person (or party) making a proposition?

Tags: single-word-requests, australian-english

The word I'm after would apply in a situation where one party proposes that another do something, and the second party accepts of rejects the proposal. In this situation, the proposal is proffered by whom?

For that matter, what is the term for the second party?

*Proposor* and *proposee* just don't sound correct.

Answer (score 0):

**offeror**
n. a person or entity who makes a specific proposal to another (the offeree) to enter into a contract.

[Legal Dictionary Definition - Offeror](http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/offeror)