# What do you call the "one who requests" and the "one who offers"?

Tags: single-word-requests, business-language, paired-word-requests

In some sort of an exchange (maybe of services, maybe of items), there are those who seek and then request, and those who offer. What would be pleasent nouns to use for these roles? "requester"/"requestor" and "offerer" don't sound right ("offerer" especially).

A shade of meaning that needs to be reflected in the nouns I'm interested in is that these cannot be ongoing services, i.e. the "offerer" does not offer you to also get some of what s/he is providing all the time to many people. If an agreement is made, the offerer will do something; otherwise s/he will not be doing it.

(Not a real) Example 1: Suppose it's a forum in which people offer or request to have a stimulating intellectual conversation about some subject. Or offer to spot someone lifting weights and request someone to spot them. Offerers, and requesters.

I know there's a [related question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35596/what-do-you-call-someone-who-makes-a-request) on "someone who makes a request", but I thought I'd ask about both terms together since the choice could be related.

Comment: I usually write "requestor" and "offeror" ...................... but I have no idea why !

Comment: You might start by [searching our site for questions containing the word *offeror*](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22offeror%22).

Comment: @MetaEd: An [unaswered question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/384575/16510), a [qeustion with answer suggestion "offeror"](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/327281/16510), and there's [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/123531/16510), which also doesn't actually offer an answer. I think that basically covers it. But you're right, I should have checked that first.

Comment: For services and goods, likely synonyms of *provider/consumer* would be the best match. For your example, you might try something like *samaritan* and *dependent*.

Comment: @jxh: Can you explain how the requestor is a "dependent"? And a "Samaritan" is one of [these people](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samaritans); how is that relevant/appropriate?

Comment: By a *samaritan*, I meant [someone that helps people](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Samaritan). By *dependent*, I meant [someone that needs someone's help](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dependent).

Comment: @jxh: Yeah, well, you can't really use Samaritan, that would be racist, even if it's attributing positive characteristics to people of certain ethnic group. It's like saying that, I don't know, someone is "practically black" because he's good at sports.

Comment: Even in 19th-century European racial theory, I don't believe Samaritans are a race. They are a people or other cultural group. Besides, it is about a positive characteristic, so there is no issue.

Comment: @Cerberus: I'm assuming you don't live in a country with Samaritans. I (usually) do.

Comment: @einpoklum: English adopted this word, and it is not considered pejorative.

Comment: Broadly, you don't. Not in modern English, anyway.

*One who requests* would be a *requester/or* but please try to find two or three people who've actually heard, let alone used that term.

*One who offers* would be an *offeror* but even harder, try to find anyone who's heard or used that term.

Answer (score -1):

If the exchange is economic, which I would say exchanges normally are, you could say *supplier* for the person offering goods or services, or *purveyor*, or else *provider* or even *giver*, or *reciprocator*. The recipient could be the *recipient* or the *buyer*, the *client*, the *seeker*, the *asker* (informal), the *beneficiary*, the *initiator*. But it depends on context: what exact situation did you have in mind? Could you give an example?

Comment: So, all of these make assumptions that can't be made in this case: "Supplier" has a supply of something; but what if it's something s/he will make? Or arrange? "Provider" suggests that it's something the offerer has to provide, or regularly produces, him/herself; but what if it's, say, an offer to do something together? "Buyer" suggests the ownership of something changes; "Client" again suggests passivity of the requestor; "asker" - what, as in a question? not clear enough.

Comment: Finally, "initiator" applies, but it's rather vague. Also, I added an example to the question.

Comment: @einpoklum: Ah, it's good that you have given an example. If *initiator* is vague, then the situation in the example is also a bit vague! I might use *initiator* and *reciprocator* in that situation. I've added *reciprocator* and *seeker* to my answer, btw.

Comment: "seeker"... that's not so bad. Reciprocator would work for a conversation, but just for examples where the interaction is reciprocal. If it were, say, for spotting a person lifting weights, it wouldn't be a reciprocator.

Comment: @einpoklum: What should I be thinking of when you say "spotting"?

Comment: This: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spotting_(weight_training)

Comment: @einpoklum: Okay, various nouns would work in that situation, like helper, assistant, provider (of the service of spotting).